# FFT window to remove noise caused by float to short convert

Tags: python, fft

Since most audio is using short format, some high freqency noise introduced due to float to short conversion!

below code simulate such scenario:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack

fs = 96000
N = 96000//2
T = 1.0/fs
x = np.arange(0,N*T,T) + T/8
y = 32767*np.sin(2*np.pi*100.0*x)
y = np.short(y)
y = y*np.hanning(len(y))

yf = np.abs(scipy.fftpack.fft(y))
yf = 20*np.log10(yf*2/N)/32767
xf = scipy.fftpack.fftfreq(N,T)

fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1,figsize=(12,12))
ax[0].plot(x,y)
ax[1].plot(xf[:N//2],yf[:N//2])
ax[1].set_xscale('log')
plt.show()
```

The output looks like below:

[image]

If I remove the short convertion line, the result is good.
How should I remove the high frequency noise? Maybe apply a special window to original signal?

Comment: You could use dithering. Maybe ask on https://dsp.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

This is quantization noise, or noise introduced by rounding or truncating sampled data to fit a smaller destination data type.  Windowing won't help, as the data will still be quantized.  You usually can't eliminate the quantization noise, but you can spread it around to make it less noticeable.  Two possible techniques are [noise shaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_shaping) and [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither).  Noise shaping spreads the rounding errors around to reduce possible accumulation and biases, possibly moving a lot of the noise to portions of the spectrum where it is less noticeable.  Dithering adds a tiny amount of noise to reduce periodic limit cycles, banding, spectral spikes/tones, and other noise artifacts that are more visible or audible than patternless randomness.